# Which universal or driverless printing solution do you use/recommend?

Tags: terminal-server, printing

I'm in need of a driverless printing solution for Microsoft Terminal Services 2003/2008.
This is mainly to support clients who are connected through broadband into our hosted servers.

We were hoping that MSTS 2008 thinprint would be the answer but unfortunately it performs poorly in the print area.  The files are too large.

I found the following slightly outdated URL: http://www.msterminalservices.org/software/Printing/

This lists a number of products but I have no experience with any of them.

I'd like a product that works/easy to install (as our clients are remote and not particularly tech savvy) and ideally I just pay for the server license and not every clients.  And something that's not going to cost too much money as we're on a tight budget.

What is your experience/recommendation and tips you can offer me in regards to TS printing?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you'll be wanting something Windows-based?

Comment: correct, its a windows environment.  We also have some mac users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try TerminalWorks TSPrint? http://www.terminalworks.com/tsprint.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm running the 30 day trial version.  It worked good for single page prints but we have an issue with multi page ones.  Could be a localized problem.  Hope this works out as the pricing is great!

Comment: Turns out I found a bug and they have (possibly) fixed it within 2 days.  A very quick response from them.  So far so good.  Will let you know how well this works.

Comment: Fantastic product. Dead simple.  Not as many features as screwdrivers but this works and does what it says.  Thank you for the suggestion oipoistar.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used it myself, but the standard answer I've read for this, for the past 10 years on Citrix fora, is Tricerat Screwdriver.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the Tricerat salesman who keeps calling me from the US wanting me to buy screwdrivers.  I was very put off by the pricing to say the least.

Comment: Ah well. I'm not surprised. Citrix commands a large premium because it still does very well what it is supposed to do. I imagine Tricerat could be the same.

Comment: If you've actually reviewed some products for the scenario you're asking about, and decided against them based on cost, that's very helpful to include in your question :-)